# Scale UIImageView in UIScrollView while rotating with UIRotationGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, rotation

I have an UIImageView in an UIScrollView. I want the UIImageView to be zoomable and rotatable.
Right now, zooming works fine.

Now I want use UIRotationGestureRecognizer to add rotation.
The problem is, that when I rotate the UIImageView, I also need to zoom it with a factor depending on the rotation angle to make sure the UIScrollView is always completely filled by  the image.

I need the math to calculate this factor. Anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just need the math, or how to perform the scale? If this isn't ios/uiimageview specific, you might want to ask in math, or just clarify that it isn't an ios question.

Comment: Someone must have done this before with IOS. Nobody?

Comment: The problem, like I said before, is that we don't understand exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: I need the factor for zooming the rotated image, so that there are no "white" parts in the scrollview which are not filled by the image.